# To pull only the specific ul inside div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have below html text -

```
<div class="a-fixed-left-grid-col a-col-left" id="zg-left-col" style="width:200px;margin-left:-200px;float:none;">
<ul id="zg_browseRoot">
<li class="zg_browseUp"> ‹

     <a href="https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers/zgbs">Any Department</a>
</li>
<ul>
<li class="zg_browseUp"> ‹

     <a href="https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers/zgbs/amazon-devices">Amazon Devices &amp; Accessories</a>
</li>
<ul>
<li>
<span class="zg_selected"> Amazon Devices</span>
</li>
<ul>
<li><a href="https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Home-Security-Amazon/zgbs/amazon-devices/17386948011">Home Security from Amazon</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Amazon-Echo-Alexa-Devices/zgbs/amazon-devices/9818047011">Amazon Echo &amp; Alexa Devices</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Dash-Buttons/zgbs/amazon-devices/10667898011">Dash Buttons</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Fire-TV/zgbs/amazon-devices/8521791011">Fire TV</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Fire-Tablets/zgbs/amazon-devices/6669703011">Fire Tablets</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Kindle-readers/zgbs/amazon-devices/6669702011">Kindle E-readers</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Amazon-Device-Bundles/zgbs/amazon-devices/16926003011">Device Bundles</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to pull somewhat like this -

```
https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Home-Security-Amazon/zgbs/amazon-devices/17386948011
https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Amazon-Echo-Alexa-Devices/zgbs/amazon-devices/9818047011
https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Dash-Buttons/zgbs/amazon-devices/10667898011
https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Fire-TV/zgbs/amazon-devices/8521791011
https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Fire-Tablets/zgbs/amazon-devices/6669703011
https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Kindle-readers/zgbs/amazon-devices/6669702011
https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Amazon-Device-Bundles/zgbs/amazon-devices/16926003011
```

I tried by using below code and its working, But not giving the result what I want.

```
soup.find('div', class_= 'a-fixed-left-grid-col a-col-left').find_all('ul')[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get all the `href` inside all the `anchor` tags.
Try this:

```
print([a['href'] for a in soup.find('div', class_= 'a-fixed-left-grid-col a-col-left').find_all('ul')[3].find_all('a')])
```

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/4915798/drec4s, this is working

Answer (score 1):

using `.select()`

```
catLinks = soup.select('#zg_browseRoot ul ul ul li a')
for link in catLinks:
    print(link.get('href'))
```